# List files in iTunes shared folder using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6, itunes

I would like to list all files in my iTunes shared folder in a '*Table View*' using *Swift*.
I check on Google and nobody talk about it, it look like it's a uncommon need, so if anyone can help it would be really helpful.

EDIT: I found three links talking about it but in Objective-C, I have no experience in this language. If someone understand this, here are the links.

> http://www.exampledb.com/objective-c-get-itunes-file-sharing-folder-files-with-full-path.htm
>   http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/10/14/ios-objective-c-working-with-files.aspx
>   http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this objective-C tutorial http://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios, I created three methods: **listFilesFromDocumentsFolder** which returns a list of the names of all documents I have in the apps iTunes shared folder and  **loadFileFromDocumentsFolder** which loads the url for a given filename and passes the url to **handleDocumentOpenUrl** to load the file on a **UIWebView**. Find below the three methods.
You can also download the project from github: https://github.com/Euniceadu/Load-Shared-Documents

**listFilesFromDocumentsFolder**

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory : String;
    documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    var fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
    var fileList: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: nil)!
    var filesStr: NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: "Files in Documents folder \n")
    for s in fileList {
        filesStr.appendFormat("%@", s as String)
    }

    self.displayAlert(filesStr)
}
```

**loadFileFromDocumentsFolder**

```
func loadFileFromDocumentsFolder(fileName: String) {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory : String;
    documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    var filePath: String = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName);
    var fileUrl: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath);
    self.handleDocumentOpenURL(fileUrl)

}
```

**handleDocumentOpenUrl**

```
func handleDocumentOpenURL(url: NSURL) {
    var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your response, but nothing work. Even by git cloning the repo I got a lot of errors. It can't work and I can't fully understand your project as there is no Storyboard.

Comment: Hi VivienG, what errors are you getting because I tested the app on my phone before committing the code. Also what version of xcode are you using?

Comment: VivienG, you can also add the url to the clone so I can check it out and see what the problem is

Comment: Hi, I use Xcode 6.0.1, I don't uderstand you second question. What do you neeed ?

Comment: I got lots of problem with UIWebView.

Comment: My second question was asking for the url to the git clone you created. Also, is it possible to state the exact errors you are having? I checked out the same code and I was able to build and run it on an iphone 5s(using ios 8.0.2) without any issues.

Comment: I use you git repo to compile.  
Here are the errors I got.

Comment: /Users/vivien/Documents/Xcode apps/Load-Shared-Documents/Read To Me/TableViewController.swift:11:1: Type 'TableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

/Users/vivien/Documents/Xcode apps/Load-Shared-Documents/Read To Me/TableViewController.swift:27:10: 'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'navigationBar'

/Users/vivien/Documents/Xcode apps/Load-Shared-Documents/Read To Me/TableViewController.swift:42:14: 'UILabel?' does not have a member named 'text'

Comment: /Users/vivien/Documents/Xcode apps/Load-Shared-Documents/Read To Me/TableViewController.swift:48:53: 'UIStoryboard?' does not have a member named 'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier'

/Users/vivien/Documents/Xcode apps/Load-Shared-Documents/Read To Me/TableViewController.swift:51:14: 'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'pushViewController'

Comment: Hello VivienG, I am very sorry but the issue had to do with the version of xcode. I used xcode6beta6 to build the app. It seems to allow certain things that xcode 6.0.1 does not allow yet. An example is the error with the navigation bar, it was throwing an error because it viewed the navigationController variable as an optional variable so i had to add an ! to unwrap it. I have downloaded xcode 6.0.1 and made the required changes to the code on github to fix it. Please update your code and try again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @euniceadu ! It look like it works. I can't be 100% sure as I use simulator and I can't add files to iTunes shared folder. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your answer, you didn't give up !

Comment: @VivienG, you're welcome. You can only add files to iTunes shared folder if you run the app from an actual device not a simulator